# When does a projection commute with an element?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, baer-rings

Let $A$ be  a Baer*-ring and $a$ be in $A$. Assume that for a projection $p\in A$,
the  following system of equations hold:

\begin{array}{ll}
   a^na^{*n}p=p  , &  n\geq0\\
   a^{*n}a^np=p  , &   n\geq0
  \end{array}

Q. Can we conclude that $ap=pa$?!

**Remark.**   In the sophsicated Baer*-ring $B(H)$, the set of all bounded operators on the Hilbert space $H$, this statement is correct.  To prove this, note that the identities $a^na^{*n}p=p$ imply that $|a^*|p=p$ and by  the other one one may similarly conclude that $|a|p=p$. Now by using the polar decomposition, the result will be obtained:

\begin{array}{ll}
   a=u|a|         & \longrightarrow  ap=up      &   \\
   a^*=u^*|a^*|   & \longrightarrow  a^*p=u^*p  &
  \end{array}

and so $ap=pa$.

Comment: With $a$ unitary your assumptions are trivially satisfied. Hence $B(H)$ certainly does not have the property that you're considering. Maybe you actually have different assumptions in mind?

Comment: @Tobias Fritz, I did not get that based on what evidence (or counterexample), you concluded  this point is not correct in $B(H)$. Any way, I added some explanations by which one may check the correctness the problem in $B(H)$.

Comment: @Ali Bagheri: no, ap=up, a*p=u*p doesn't imply ap=pa. See Tobias Fritz's comment. Because in your edit pa=(a*p)*=(u*p)*=pu, which is different from up=ap. One of the easiest counterexamples is p=projection on x-axis, in dimension 2, and u:(x,y)->(-y,x).

Comment: @Luca Ghidelli:  Thanks, you are right. It needs more condition to be correct even in $B(H)$.